# Shorten a URL with HREF link

Tags: php, url

ok i'm trying to shorten a url but keep the actual link intact.

I'm using this code at the moment, can't find a simple working solution...

```
$description = preg_replace('/https?:\/\/[^\s<]+/i', '<a href="\0">\0</a>', $description);
```

example of what i want to achieve.

input    http://www.example.com/839283ur9283ru2938u2389ru23irj3.html

output   http://www.example.com/839283u...

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/839283ur9283ru2938u2389ru23irj3.html">http://www.example.com/839283u...</a>
```

i need it to automatically find url links in a description and make them active? while cutting them down to a given length.

ty

Answer (score 2):

try with [parse_url()](http://uk.php.net/parse_url) and [substr()](http://uk.php.net/substr)

```
$url = parse_url('http://www.example.com/839283ur9283ru2938u2389ru23irj3.html');
$newUrl = $url['scheme'].'://'.$url['host'].substr($url['path'], 0, 8);
echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$newUrl.'...</a>';
```

Comment: i need it to automatically find url links in a description and make them active? while cutting them down to a given length.